# Reading/meaning of 裡

Tags: meaning, kanji, readings

> 日頃は冷静な乾さんの裡から、ちらりと激情が見えたようだった。

What is the reading and meaning of 裡 here? I found the readings うち and うら in Jisho.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [ふりがな文庫](https://furigana.info/w/%E8%A3%A1), the most frequent kun-reading is うち. うち is mentioned in [this entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%86%E3%81%A1/#jn-19186), but うら is not mentioned in [this entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%86%E3%82%89/#jn-20650). However うち, うら and なか equally make sense in your sentence, and I don't think it possible to determine the reading in one way without furigana. They are fairly rare kun-readings, anyway. FWIW, I knew only the on-reading, り, as in 秘密裡.